# ASIHTTPRequest - Response Correct in Debug Window but Null in Browser

Tags: php, iphone, asihttprequest

I've never used ASIHTTPRequest before, nor have I dealt with posting anything from an iPhone to a web service before. I'd like to eventually save the posted variables to a database, but I am unsure if they are being posted properly at this time. When I run the following script in Xcode, I see the correct html code with inserted variables logged in the debug window. My concern is that I don't see the same thing when I access the page in the browser. My guess is this is to be expected, but I'm not completely sure. Here is what I am doing:

```
string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Did this"];
string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"come through?"];

NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myurl.com/post_test.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:string1 forKey:@"String1"];
[request setPostValue:string2 forKey:@"String2"];
NSString *response = nil;
[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    response = [request responseString];


    NSLog(@"Response GOOD: %@", response);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Response BAD: %@", error);
}
```

This prints the html code from the web page with the uploaded variables correctly, but if I go to the page in my browser the php variables are null. Here is the small php script:

```
<?php

    $received = array();
    $received = $_POST;
    $print_received = print_r($received, TRUE);
    echo "<pre>$print_received</pre>";
    $var1 = $received['String1'];
    $var2 = $received['String2'];
    echo "The message received was: $var1 $var2</br>";

?>
```

I haven't added the mysql connection code yet because I want to make sure this posting business is successful first.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a database in PHP?

Comment: What I am wondering is, should I be concerned that the response I get printed in my Xcode command window is accurate, but I don't see these changes reflected on the page if viewed through the browser?

Comment: I think what he's asking is why the parameters he sent in the POST request don't seem to be making it into the `$_POST` array in PHP.  The database may be a bit of a red herring.

Comment: You are submitting the vars via `POST` when you test with your browser, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting the correct response from the code that you posted, it means your code is working. What is probably happening is that you're not using `POST` when testing with your browser.

Check to make sure `$_POST[]` actually contains data *first*. If not, presumably you'd want to output a meaningful error. It looks like you're just building a sandbox of sorts to play and get familiar with ASIHTTPRequest, however if your goals get more complex (and your code becomes public facing) you'll want to spend some time reading up on how to sanitize and validate `POST/GET` variables before using them.

Comment: This should be set as the correct answer since it correctly points out that you should be POSTing data to the page when testing your script in a browser and not just going to the page directly, which would only set GET variables and not POST variables.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned databases in your question, I assume that isn't what you are looking for.

Look into [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php). It allows you to easily store and retrieve variables in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed that the variables are being posted properly by writing the variables to a text file:

```
$file = "received_text.txt";
$fh = fopen( $file, 'a' ) or die("Cannot open file");
fwrite( $fh, $var1 );
fwrite( $fh, ", ");
fwrite( $fh, $var2 );
fwrite( $fh, "\n" );
fclose( $fh );
```

I can now proceed.

Comment: You'll _probably_ want to make a form to post to that script as it gains complexity so you can tickle it with your browser. I'm glad you got this worked out, and I'm sorry about the rude answers you received :)

Comment: Hah yea. That guy was a jerk. Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'make a form to post to that script'? Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Well, from your question it looked like you were making a request like  `http://server/script.php?var1=foo&var2=bar` for testing. This would, of course, set `GET`, but not `POST` variables.